# How to send custom tweet with link and images in ios?

Tags: ios, tweets, slrequest

I know that how to send custom tweet using SLRequest and TWRequest but i didn't get link when i post message and link. I got only message.

The code is:

```
  NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Send to text",@"status",@"http://stackoverflow.com/",@"link", nil];
  SLRequest *slRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"] parameters:dict];
 [slRequest setAccount:account];//account is ACAcount type object

 [slRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error){
                                NSLog(@"The responseString:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

                            }];
```

I think the problem is at key value for sending link . Here i am using 'link' key. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There no parameter like link for update URL . 
you need to append your URl to status and set true for `wrap_links` parameter.It will work

```
//change your dict like below
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Send to text http://stackoverflow.com/"],@"status",@"true",@"wrap_links", nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am not getting. Please explain briefly

Answer (score 0):

same goes with the Facebook SLRequest except that the key for 'status' is 'message'.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey %@ check this out http://stackoverflow.com/", self.label.text],@"message",@"true",@"wrap_links", nil];
```